# Biggest and Smallest Number Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

1. Challenge:

   - You are given a string of space-separated numbers and have to return the highest and lowest number.
2. Problem:

   - Expected: '542 -214', instead got: '6 -214'
   - I can't understand why the system thinks 6 is higher than 542. The program works fine when the 6 is removed.
3. Code:

   ```
   function highAndLow(numbers){
      numbers = numbers.split(" ");
      var biggest = numbers[0];
      for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         if (numbers[i] > biggest) {
            biggest = numbers[i];
         }
      }
      var smallest = numbers[0];
      for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = numbers[i];
         }
      }
      return biggest + " " + smallest;
      }

   console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
   ```

   [JSBin Link](https://jsbin.com/ravihek/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: You got an array of strings. You need to cast it to an int.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's comparing the numbers as strings instead of as numbers. You'll want to [convert them to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/9420243) using the [`Number()`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_number.asp) function to convert them to numbers before you compare them, for example:

```
biggest = Number(numbers[0]);
```

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to this question. This is an often-posted duplicate.